# Javascript syntax for abbreviating repeated access to same identifier

Tags: javascript

I wanted to ask if there is a formal way of describing the following code, whereby we can access the same object repeatedly without re-typing the object's identifier:

```
myObj.render(1).render(2).print();
```

I didn't know how to describe it when trying to form a question; I wanted to know whether or not something like this is possible in javascript, I know that I can do it in VB:

```
myObj.render(1)
    if(foo == 'bar')
        .render(2)
    .print();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name you are looking for is [*fluent interface*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), your first example can easily be implemented like this:

```
var obj = {
  render: function (arg) {
    // do something here...
    return this; // the key of chainability
  },
  print: function () {
    alert('print something...');
  }
};

obj.render(1).render(2).print();
```

Basically the `render` method needs to return the object instance where it belongs, in order to allow *chainability*.

The conditional you want to do is not possible, you'll have make something like [@musicfreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035128/javascript-syntax-for-abbreviating-repeated-access-to-same-identifier/3035141#3035141) suggest.

Comment: I didn't know that, I always wondered how jQuery did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
var obj = myObj.render(1);
if (foo == 'bar')
  obj = obj.render(2);
obj.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would go for:

```
var x = myObj.render(1);
if(foo == 'bar')
   x = x.render(2);
x.print();
```

You may also be interested in the `with` keyword, as in:

```
var a, x, y;
var r = 10;
with (Math) {
   a = PI * r * r;
   x = r * cos(PI);
   y = r * sin(PI / 2);
}
```

More details about it can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/With)